# Can you use combat expertise with no melee targets?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Picture the scenario: A skillful fighter finds himself being targeted by a clutch of archers. He can't close the distance in time, but he does have that handy combat expertise feat to give him a much-needed AC boost. The problem is, combat expertise must be part of an attack action and there is no one within range to attack.

Thematically my DM has allowed me to do it because if a fighter is skilled enough to sacrifice offense for defense while in combat against a melee enemy, he should certainly have the ability to do it when there is no melee target distracting him.

My question is - is there a specific rule that says you cannot do this? More broadly, is there a rule that says you can *only* take the Attack action if there is a valid target?

Comment: Just that Combat Expertise is better for AC at +5 Base Attack Bonus or higher and you can still make attacks of opportunity,  as KRyan points out below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Strictly speaking, [you can declare an attack against the environment](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm#smashinganObject), even the ground (it has AC 5, if you were wondering; this is relevant for so-called “splash weapons”). So yes, you can “use the attack action” against the floor or whatever, and gain the benefit of Combat Expertise if you feel the need. If your DM actually makes you describe your character attacking the floor in order to do this, you are playing a much sillier game than I’m used to.

If you have at least BAB +5, this is numerically superior to the total defense action (which is a +4 dodge bonus), though even at lower levels it’s still arguably superior since it doesn’t prevent you from taking attacks of opportunity. Note you do take whatever penalty you choose on any AoOs that happen though.

Comment: Bears mentioning: Can I [fight defensively](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/actionsInCombat.htm#fightingDefensivelyasaFullRoundAction) *versus* the planet, too, therefore gaining that bonus and the bonus from the feat [Combat Expertise](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#combatExpertise)?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Huh, never noticed (since I consider all of these options a waste of time), but strictly speaking Fighting Defensively doesn’t define itself as a full-attack, just as a full-round action. It says “all attacks” but after a full-round action, there’s a good chance you aren’t *getting* any attacks, unless someone provokes from you. Clearly an oversight, but without specific wording it’s hard to say if it’s compatible with Combat Expertise...

Comment: One can fight defensively as a standard action, too, though, and that explicitly stacks in the *Player's Handbook* (140). I just thought that'd be useful to the asker, too, as might be the bonus to fighting defensively *via* the skill Tumble. (Hey, if you're gonna do it...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but do you have a citation for "you can attack the environment"?

Comment: @WannabeCoder ["Smashing an object is a lot like sundering a weapon or shield, except that your attack roll is opposed by the object’s AC."](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/exploration.htm#smashinganObject). Take *that*, insolent planet!

Comment: On occasion, this can even be useful; *mountain hammer*-ing through a wall, for example.